# Identifying "Access violation reading location" exception thrown in my code

Tags: c++, multithreading, threadpool

I'm a first year software engineering student and this is my second unit so far. so go easy on me please haha

My threadpool program (code largely been supplied to me from uni and additions sourced from code blacksmith on YT), throws me the error:

> Exception thrown at 0x7B547643 (msvcp140d.dll) in "project_name".exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000014.

My teacher tells me *"this mutex call error means you are not using mutex correctly"*, but it seems to me I'm using them correctly.

I read on another question here that *"Access violation reading location 0x000000whatever" means that you're derefrencing a pointer that hasn't been initialized and therefore has garbage values*.

Buut I can't seem to find the source of this dereferenced pointer..
Could someone please look at my code and tell me whats going on??
for all I can tell, it should be working.

**Note**: it does build, but won't compile and I'm still working on it so there may be same garbage #inlcudes or using std::'s.

Threadpool.h

```
 
#pragma once
#include <thread>
#include <vector>
#include "CTask.h"
#include "WorkQueue.h"

using std::thread;
using std::vector;
using std::mutex;
using std::ref;

extern unsigned int h_ThreadCapacity;

class Threadpool
{
public:
    ~Threadpool()
    {
        Stop();
    }; 

    void Initialize()
    {
        m_iNumberOfThreads = h_ThreadCapacity;
    };

    void Submit(CTask _iworkItem) // Enqueue
    {
        {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock{ m_WorkQueue->m_WorkQMutex } ;
            m_WorkQueue->push(_iworkItem);
        }

        m_WorkQueue->m_WorkQCondition.notify_one();

    };

    
    void Start()
    {
        for (int i = 0u; i < m_iNumberOfThreads; i++)
        {
            m_workerThreads.emplace_back([=] {
                while (true)
                {
                    CTask task;

                    { 
                        unique_lock<mutex> lock{ m_WorkQueue->m_WorkQMutex };

                        m_WorkQueue->m_WorkQCondition.wait(lock, [=] {return m_Stopping || !m_WorkQueue->empty(); });

                        if (m_Stopping && m_WorkQueue->empty())
                            break;

                        //if not stopping...
                        task = move(m_WorkQueue->workQ.front()); 
                        m_WorkQueue->workQ.pop(); 
                    } 

                    task.update(); // execute task
                }
            });
        }
    };

    void Stop() 
    {
        {
            lock_guard<mutex> lock{ m_WorkQueue->m_WorkQMutex };
            m_Stopping = true;
        }
        
        m_WorkQueue->m_WorkQCondition.notify_all();
        // join threads
        for (auto& threads : m_workerThreads)
        {
            threads.join();
        }
    };

    static Threadpool& getInstance()
    {
        static Threadpool s_Instance;
        return s_Instance;
    }


private:
    //Constructor in private to create singleton
    Threadpool() {
        Initialize();
    }

    Threadpool(Threadpool const&) = delete; // singleton non-copyable 
    void operator = (Threadpool const&) = delete; // singleton un-assignable
    
protected:
    static Threadpool* s_pThreadPool; // this is for singleton, given by uni, though not gonna use it.

private:

    WorkQueue<CTask>* m_WorkQueue;

    vector<thread> m_workerThreads;

    unsigned int m_iNumberOfThreads;

    volatile bool isRunning;
    bool m_Stopping = false;

};
```

WorkQueue.h

```
#pragma once

#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include "CTask.h"

using std::queue;
using std::lock_guard;
using std::unique_lock;
using std::mutex;
using std::condition_variable;
using std::move;

template<typename T>
class WorkQueue
{
public:
    WorkQueue() {}
    //Insert an item at the back of the queue and signal any thread that might be waiting
    //for the queue to be populated
    void push(const T& item)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> _lock(m_WorkQMutex);
        workQ.push(move(item));//copies over all the data correctly
        m_WorkQCondition.notify_one();
    }

    //Attempt to get a workitem from the queue
    //If the queue is empty just return false;
    bool nonblocking_pop(T& _workItem) // use first.. ?
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> _lock(m_WorkQMutex);
        //If the queue is empty return false
        if (workQ.empty())
        {
            return false;
        }
        _workItem = move(workQ.front());
        workQ.pop();
        return true;
    }

    //Attempt to get a workitem from the queue
    //If the Q is empty just return false;
    void blocking_pop(T& _workItem) // IF task still needs to be completed
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> _lock(m_WorkQMutex);
        //If the queue is empty block the thread from running until a work item
        //becomes available
        m_WorkQCondition.wait(_lock, [this] {return !workQ.empty(); });
        _workItem = move(workQ.front());
        workQ.pop();
    }

    //Checking if the queue is empty or not
    bool empty() const
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> _lock(m_WorkQMutex);
        return workQ.empty();
    }

    queue<T> workQ;
    mutable mutex m_WorkQMutex;
    condition_variable m_WorkQCondition;

private:
};
```

CTask.h

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include<Windows.h>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class CTask {
private:
    int sleepTimer;

public:
    CTask()//gets called at creation of an object
    {
        sleepTimer = 10;
    }; 

    ~CTask() {};

    void update()
    {
        //may be sleep
        cout << "\n\t...Beginning task..." << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(sleepTimer));
        cout << "\n\t   Task Complete!" << endl;
    }; 
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "WorkQueue.h"
#include "Threadpool.h"
#include "CTask.h"

using std::thread;
using std::vector;

unsigned int h_ThreadCapacity = thread::hardware_concurrency();

int main()
{
    Threadpool& tPool = Threadpool::getInstance(); // create the threadpool
    CTask task; // instance of task object

    tPool.Start();
    tPool.Submit(task);

}
```

Comment: `m_WorkQueue` is not being initialized.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, now would be a great time to learn how to use the debugger, as that would most likely drop you in right at the error.

Comment: `0x00000014` looks like accessing a member at that offset through a null pointer.

Comment: Whenever you get a crash, you should first of all try to replicate the crash. If you can easily replicate it, then you should use a *debugger* to catch the crash and locate when and where in *your* code it happens.

Comment: In `Submit` at `unique_lock<mutex> lock{ m_WorkQueue->m_WorkQMutex }`, `m_WorkQueue` is `NULL`. You debugger more or tells you this.

Comment: Oh riiight, okay. that makes a lot of sense.
@Jabberwocky how would I initialize m_WorkQueue in this case? and where?

It's early days with the debugger for me so i'm still getting the handle of it, somedays it confuses me more than it tells haha.

Comment: @chonkychoi spent an hour or two learning the debugger. This time will pay off very quickly.

Comment: Search for the error message online to get an idea what it means. In this case, you're accessing address 0x14, which is typically 20 bytes offset from a null pointer. Use `assert()` to document you expect valid pointers or other invariants. Also, for a question here, extract a [mcve] first, which also helps you to focus on the problem. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: How to initialize `m_WorkQueue` : `m_WorkQueue` is a _pointer_ that is never initialized, so it points nowhere. `m_WorkQueue` probably should not be a pointer: `m_WorkQueue->` -> `m_WorkQueue.` and `WorkQueue<CTask> *m_WorkQueue` -> `WorkQueue<CTask> m_WorkQueue`. There may be other problems though, I didn't check.

Comment: okay awesome, yeah will do. thanks for the help & tips everyone!

Comment: _"it does build, but won't compile"_: actually you mean: _"it does build, but won't run correctly"_

Comment: @Jabberwocky awesome, thanks for the insights.  the WorkQueue declaration was actually in the skeleton code from the uni so i've been trying to work around it haha. I'll look into changing it! (as you can probably tell, haven't fully wrapped my head around pointers either)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude What does *"replicate the crash"* mean? Does it mean the *same* crash should occur every time when executing the code, or does it mean we should make a minimal reproducible example? (what if it's difficult to know whether it's the same crash without a debugger in the first place?)

Comment: Being able to reliably cause the same crash happen over and over again so you're able to debug it. If it's not possible to reliably cause the same crash to happen again, it's much harder to debug.